# GWT places and activities - getting duplicate UI

Tags: java, gwt

I am new to GWT and trying to implement activities and places. I am facing a problem with the UI. I can't post an image because I am new to Stackoverflow and doesn't have 10 reputation points but I am seeing a panel on the left twice. I have also attached the launcher code and UI binder code.

```
public class SmartEBRM implements EntryPoint {
//private Place defaultPlace = new SmartEBRMViewPlace("World!");

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ClientFactory clientFactory = GWT.create(ClientFactory.class);
    EventBus eventBus = clientFactory.getEventBus();
    PlaceController placeController = clientFactory.getPlaceController();

    // Start ActivityManager for the main widget with our ActivityMapper
    ActivityMapper activityMapper = new AppActivityMapper(clientFactory);
    ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(activityMapper, eventBus);
    SmartEBRMViewImpl smartViewImpl = new SmartEBRMViewImpl();
    activityManager.setDisplay (smartViewImpl.getHTMLPannel());


    // Start PlaceHistoryHandler with our PlaceHistoryMapper
    AppPlaceHistoryMapper historyMapper= GWT.create(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
    PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(historyMapper);
    SmartEBRMViewPlace smartViewPlace = new SmartEBRMViewPlace();
    historyHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, smartViewPlace);
    historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();

    RootPanel.get().add(smartViewImpl);
}
}
```

and

```
public class SmartEBRMViewImpl extends Composite implements SmartEBRMView{
private static SmartEBRMViewImplUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(SmartEBRMViewImplUiBinder.class);

@UiField DockLayoutPanel docLayoutPanel;
@UiField StackPanel stackPanel;
@UiField Button enterpriseView;
@UiField Button testComponent;
@UiField SimplePanel centerPanel;

private Presenter listener;

interface SmartEBRMViewImplUiBinder extends
        UiBinder<Widget, SmartEBRMViewImpl> {
}

public SmartEBRMViewImpl() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

public SmartEBRMViewImpl(String firstName) {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@Override
public void setPresenter(Presenter listener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.listener = listener;

}

public SimplePanel getHTMLPannel () {
    return centerPanel;
}

@UiHandler("enterpriseView")
public void onClearButtonClick(ClickEvent e)
{
    listener.goTo(new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace());
}
}
```

Comment: Why did you suppress "deprecated"? Do you use an old version of an EventBus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add your view directly to the RootPanel. Instead, you should add your appWidget:

```
activityManager.setDisplay (appWidget);
RootPanel.get().add(appWidget);
```

The ActivityManager will add and hide views as you navigate from one Place to the next.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. This is what I did now.RootPanel.get().add(smartViewImpl.getHTMLPannel()); but I want to keep my menu constant on every page. Now when I click on the Button, it navigates me to new page. I want to do that but keeping my left menu constant on every page. I want to understand the difference between activityManager.setDisplay (smartViewImpl.getHTMLPannel()); and RootPanel.get().add(smartViewImpl.getHTMLPannel());. I don't actually what they are doing.

Comment: There two options: create a Widget that represents your menu, and add this widget to each view. Or, split your app into two parts: menu part and content part, and have a separate ActivityManager for each one. You can read more about this solution here: http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I think I got it :) (+1)